# How can I create multiple different admin roles with their own capabilities

Tags: admin, user-roles, capabilities

I would like to create multiple Admin roles to manage only particular custom-post types that I assign to them. They would not be able to add/edit/delete custom-posts that they don't have rights to.

Has anybody done anything like this before?

Thanks, Adam

Comment: If this is only about (custom) posts, why do they need to be admins? Doesn't editor role suffice?

Comment: Yes Editor role would suffice - is this easier to do for editors? - to have them given rights to edit only particular custom post types of my choosing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very easy. You'll want to use the add_role() function to add your custom roles - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

Then you can use add_cap to add custom capabilities - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

One important thing to mention is that both add_role and add_cap are saved to the database so they only need to run 1x so it's good to hook these functions into theme_switch, load-themes.php or if it's in a plugin using register_activation_hook

There is also another good answer can be found here with an example: [Apply custom role capabilities to administrator (without plugin)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74853/apply-custom-role-capabilities-to-administrator-without-plugin)