# only a certain role has access to a cpt

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I have a "barbershop" custom post type and i want to have a "barber" role in my wordpress. I wrote this code so my barber would have access to write or delete his own barbershop.

```
// Barbershop Post Type
function register_barbershop() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                                  =>  __('آرایشگاه ها', 'noosh'),
        'singular_name'                         =>  __('آرایشگاه', 'noosh'),
        'add_new'                               =>  __('افزودن', 'noosh'),
        'add_new_item'                          =>  __('افزودن آرایشگاه تازه', 'noosh'),
        'edit_item'                             =>  __('ویرایش آرایشگاه', 'noosh'),
        'new_item'                              =>  __('آرایشگاه تازه', 'noosh'),
        'view_item'                             =>  __('نمایش آرایشگاه', 'noosh'),
        'view_items'                            =>  __('نمایش آرایشگاه ها', 'noosh'),
        'all_items'                             =>  __('همه ی آرایشگاه ها', 'noosh'),

    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                                =>  $labels,
        'public'                                =>  true,
        'capability_type'                       =>  'bshop',
        'map_meta_cap'                          =>  true,
        'supports'                              =>  array('title', 'editor', 'comments', 'author', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type('barbershop', $args);
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_barbershop' );

// Add barber user role
function add_barber() {
    $caps = [
        'read'                    => true,
        'edit_bshop'              => true,
        'read_bshop'              => true,
        'delete_bshop'            => true,

        'edit_bshops'             => true,
        'edit_others_bshops'      => false,
        'publish_bshops'          => true,
        'read_private_bshops'     => true,

        'delete_bshops'           => true,
        'delete_private_bshops'   => true,
        'delete_published_bshops' => true,
        'delete_others_bshops'    => false,
        'edit_private_bshops'     => true,
        'edit_published_bshops'   => true,
    ];

    add_role( 'barber', 'آرایشگر', $caps );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_barber' );
```

But there is one problem, just only my barber has access to this barbershop cpt, not superadmin. I want that my admin can manage the barbershop too, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add these new capabilities to the admin role too.

Maybe this question would help you:
[Apply custom role capabilities to administrator (without plugin)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74853/apply-custom-role-capabilities-to-administrator-without-plugin)